# Making shared_ptr lose ownership of memory

Tags: c++, c++11, protocol-buffers, shared-ptr

I have a `shared_ptr<MyProto>` which I pass around. Eventually, in certain situations, I want pass the raw pointer to a function which then becomes the memory owner. In those cases the `shared_ptr` isn't responsible anymore for freeing the memory because the function I call took ownership. How do I get the `shared_ptr` to lose ownership?

The reason I want to have the `shared_ptr` lose ownership is that I want to use protocol buffer's AddAllocated functionality which takes an already allocated pointer and assumes ownership of it.

Example:

```
shared_ptr<MyProto> myProtoSharedPtr = // by this point this is the last reference to the heap allocated MyProto

// I want to add it to a collection and serialize the collection without copying
CollectionProto collectionProto;
collectionProto.mutable_my_proto().AddAllocated(myProtoSharedPtr.get()); // at this point collectionProto took ownership of the memory
std::string serialization = collectionProto.SerializeAsString();

// bad: myProtoSharedPtr.get() will be freed twice
```

Comment: Why are you using a shared pointer?

Comment: Because this memory is passed around a lot and not always added to a collcetion

Comment: This doesn't make sense.. This `shared_ptr` want to release the ownership, how about the other `shared_ptr`s sharing ownership?

Comment: See comment where I add to the collection - it's the sole owner at this point

Comment: Call `myProtoSharedPtr.reset()`

Comment: You have to release ownership from **every** `std::shared_ptr` that has it. This is not a very safe thing to do imo. What if you miss one?

Comment: @Hitobat This would release the memory if this is the last shared_ptr.

Comment: What you want is hardly doable, for the above mentioned reasons concerning shared ownership, but also because you don't know how the memory was allocated. If the shared pointer was created using `make_shared`, you likely have a single block of memory holding both the object and the control block, so you'd have to destroy the control block with the object, but how would you do if it's one or the other if you only have a pointer to the object?

Comment: Do you control the function taking an owning raw pointer?

Comment: @Caleth - I don't, if I did I'd have it take a shared_ptr

Comment: If you know there is a unique `shared_ptr` owner, why do you even need `shared_ptr`? If you don't know that, how do you communicate with any code owning another `shared_ptr` owner to withdraw it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you can achieve what you want to do by *sharing* a *unique 
 pointer* like this:

```
std::shared_ptr<std::unique_ptr<MyProto>> myProtoSharedUniquePtr;
```

Accessing it would be more indirect:

```
(*myProtoSharedUniquePtr)->do_stuff();
```

But you could take ownership like this:

```
CollectionProto collectionProto;
collectionProto.mutable_my_proto().AddAllocated(myProtoSharedUniquePtr->release()); // at this point collectionProto took ownership of the memory
std::string serialization = collectionProto.SerializeAsString();
```

However I would question why you are using a `std::shared_ptr` to begin with. The reason to use a `std::shared_ptr` is when you have no control over who will be last to access it, so each one gets to keep it alive until they are done. So it would be unusual to be able to guarantee all current `std::shared_ptr` instances are no longer in use.

Are you sure a `std::unique_ptr` would not be better for your needs?

Answer (score 7):

You could use a `unique_ptr`, which is anyhow better suited for passing memory around:

```
unique_ptr<MyProto> myProtoSharedPtr = // create MyPorto object

CollectionProto collectionProto;

// unique_ptr::release returns the pointer and
// releases the ownership of the MyProto object
collectionProto.mutable_my_proto().AddAllocated(myProtoSharedPtr.release());

std::string serialization = collectionProto.SerializeAsString();
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to provide `std::shared_ptr` with a [custom deleter](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr) (See constructor 4). Then you can define the deleter to do what you want. Including, not destroy your object.

*Note 1: I don't recomend using shared_ptr here, but this is a way to do what you want.*

*Note 2: If you use `make_shared` to create your objects you will likely run into trouble correctly deleting the memory once the last shared_ptr is removed.*

Comment: Regarding your second note: `make_shared` does not support a custom deleter for that exact reason. Single allocation is still possible with `allocate_shared`, and putting the "deleter" logic in the allocator, but unfortunately, `shared_ptr`'s public API does not support allocator access for doing, in this case, a `release()`. A workaround would be to put a `shouldDelete` flag in the object itself, IOW, using a bigger shoehorn…

Answer (score 1):

You could use std::move when you want to transfer the ownership, see the following example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
void take_ownership(std::shared_ptr<int> ptr){
std::cout<<ptr.use_count()<<" == 2\n";
} // destroying it


int main()
{
std::shared_ptr<int> p=std::make_shared<int>(1);
std::shared_ptr<int> p2(p);
//p is valid                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
if(!p.get())
std::cout<<"error\n";
else
std::cout<<"OK\n";

//use p, p2

take_ownership(std::move(p));
//p is invalid                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
if(!p.get())
std::cout<<"OK\n";
else
std::cout<<p.use_count()<<" error\n";

}
```

Comment: My answer to the question was to use to std::move to transfer the shared ownership. using  weak_ptr only confuses things and it's not necessary for this example.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than copying, you could move it into a `new`ed object.

```
MyProto * myProto = new MyProto(std::move(*mySharedProto));

CollectionProto collectionProto;
collectionProto.mutable_my_proto().AddAllocated(myProto);
```

You could also investigate whether `CollectionProto` will accept it by value

```
CollectionProto collectionProto;
collectionProto.mutable_my_proto().Add(std::move(*mySharedProto));
```